# How open uploaded file in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to write a library application on django rest framework.
I have two models: File and Book:

```
class File(models.Model):
file = models.FileField(upload_to="books//%Y/%m/")


class Book(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    path = models.TextField()
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    last_access = models.BinaryField()
    cover_image = models.BinaryField()
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='uploaded_files', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author + ' - ' + self.title
```

Serializator and view

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = "__all__"

class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

How can i open uploaded file in ModelViewSet? Or i must use a generic APIView to override put/post operation for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is simple.

```
class AddFile(APIView):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            file_path = media_root + file_serializer.data['file']
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                # do something with file
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Media root get from settings.MEDIA_ROOT and trim.